Set up enhanced conversions
I need help with setting up enhanced conversions for my client.
I created new conversions due to instructions, in GTM everything is good, my new conversions are working, but I still can't see them in my Google Ads account
according to the instructions, I enabled advanced conversion tracking in Google Ads and set up new conversions for phone numbers in GTM
